# Why is Compiler is saying there is no group with name <NUMBER>?

Tags: java, regex

I am making Lexical analyzer. LINE 1-30 are imports
FUNCTION init() just initializes HASHTABLE for keyword.
enum at LINE 61 "TokenType" specifies the tokens which are going to be taken.
I am getting an error saying no group with name  when clearly I have declared NUMBER.
LINE 96 uses the matcher engine to match.
LINE 97 if a group is matched @ LINE 98 creates a token and returns and matcher moves on to the next one.

```
public static enum TokenType{
   ADDSUB("[+|-]?"),NUMBER("-?[0-9]+"),
INCDEC("[[++]|[--]]"),DIVMOD("[/|%]"),
ID("[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*"),
MUL("[*]+"), WHITESPACE("[ \t\f\r\n]+");
public final String pattern;

    private TokenType(String pattern){
    this.pattern=pattern;
    }
  }
   /*we declare a data structure for holding the token data*/
  public static class Token{
    public TokenType type;
    public String Data;
    public Token(TokenType type,String Data){
        this.type=type;
        this.Data=Data;
    }
    @Override
     public String toString() {
  return String.format("(%s %s)", type.name(), Data);
    }
     }

     public static ArrayList<Token> lex(String input) {
// The tokens to return
        ArrayList<Token> tokens = new ArrayList<Token>();

// Lexer logic begins here
        StringBuffer tokenPatternsBuffer = new StringBuffer();
      for(TokenType tokenType :TokenType.values()){
      tokenPatternsBuffer.append(String.format("|(?<%s>%s)",    tokenType.name(), tokenType.pattern));

    Pattern tokenPatterns=Pattern.compile(tokenPatternsBuffer.substring(1));
      // Begin matching tokens
         Matcher matcher = tokenPatterns.matcher(input);
            while(matcher.find())       
    {if(matcher.group(TokenType.NUMBER.name())!=null){ tokens.add(new Token(TokenType.NUMBER,matcher.group(TokenType.NUMBER.name())));
      continue;
  } else if(matcher.group(TokenType.ID.name())!=null){
      if(KW.containsValue(matcher.pattern())){
          System.out.println("y");

 tokens.add(new   Token(TokenType.ID,matcher.group(TokenType.ID.name())));
      }
      else{
          System.out.println("n");

 tokens.add(newToken(TokenType.ID,matcher.group(TokenType.ID.name())));  
      continue;
      }
     }
        }

     }
     return tokens;
             }
```

Comment: Instead of *describing* your code, *post* it. This will be simpler for everyone.

Comment: Looks like some syntax error as enum TokenType has closing brace before public final String pattern.

Comment: @Guy I have attached the full code

Comment: A pipe inside `[...]` matches a literal pipe, you need to remove all pipes in cases where it is inside character classes. Besides, `INCDEC("[[++]|[--]]")` must be defined as `INCDEC("(?:\\+\\+|--)")` since you want to match one of two sequences of symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static enum TokenType{



    ADDSUB("[+|-]?"),NUMBER("-?[0-9]+"),
    INCDEC("[[++]|[--]]"),DIVMOD("[/|%]"),
    ID("[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*"),
    MUL("[*]+"), WHITESPACE("[ \t\f\r\n]+");


    public final String pattern;

    private TokenType(String pattern){
        this.pattern=pattern;
    }
}
```

**Corrected code** as shown above.

Comment: Problem remains the same